# Water Bill Calculator (VB.NET) issues

Tags: vb.net

I am having a few issues with my Water Bill program written in VB.

Basically what I have to do is create an application that calculates a customer’s water bill. The user will enter the current meter reading and the previous meter reading. The application should calculate and display the number of gallons of water used and the total charge for the water.

The charge for water is $1.75 per 1000 gallons, or 0.00175 per gallon.

First off my most frustrating issue is the fact that I get this error `The class waterBill can be designed, but is not the first class in the file.` I was copying and pasting code from a forum to see how it would work. I had no intention of keeping the code, I was just testing it and when I tried to revert to my original code, this error persisted. I don't understand how the errors are still there when I deleted the copied code.

The second thing is I can't get my calculator to make any calculations. Every time I press calculate it displays 0. Here is my VB code...

```
Public Class waterBill

Dim currentReading As Integer
Dim previousReading As Integer
Dim gallonsUsed As Integer
Dim totalCharge As Decimal

Private Sub calculateCharge()
    If (currentReading >= previousReading) Then
        gallonsUsed = currentReading - previousReading
        totalCharge = gallonsUsed * 0.00175
        ElseIf (currentReading < previousReading) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Current reading must be greater than or equal to previous reading", "Water Bill Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub displayCharge()
        txtGallonsUsed.Text = gallonsUsed
        txtTotalCharge.Text = totalCharge
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Call calculateCharge()
        Call displayCharge()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Hope my little ramble makes sense.

Comment: UPDATE: So changed the class name and now no errors are showing. Also design window is working properly.

Comment: so what is your current and previous reading? you need a value for that so your calculation will not be zero

Comment: The first problem is fixed. Chinz, the current and previous reading is what the user types. But no matter what I type I get 0 for both values.

Comment: @YoungMogul I didnt see where you retrieve the user input

Comment: Please edit your question (and title) to focus on the current issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

```
'Declaring a integer variable will make it as 0 by default, you need to set the value.
Dim currentReading As Integer
Dim previousReading As Integer
Dim gallonsUsed As Integer
Dim totalCharge As Decimal

Private Sub calculateCharge()
    'I suppose you're missing two input control to set the value of currentReading and previousReading 
    previousReading = CInt(txtPrevious.Text)
    currentReading = CInt(txtCurrent.Text)

    If (currentReading >= previousReading) Then
        gallonsUsed = currentReading - previousReading
        totalCharge = gallonsUsed * 0.00175
    ElseIf (currentReading < previousReading) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Current reading must be greater than or equal to previous reading", "Water Bill Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub displayCharge()
    txtGallonsUsed.Text = gallonsUsed
    txtTotalCharge.Text = totalCharge
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Call calculateCharge()
    Call displayCharge()
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: That would make sense.